# Trazer valor de outra célula para a fórmula sem ser String

Tags: microsoft-excel

A fórmula no excel `PROCV` procura verticalmente um valor em uma tabela específica de uma coluna X.

Visto isso, tenho o seguinte problema com esta fórmula:

```
=PROCV(J7;JUL;6;JUL!C4:C35)
```

Com isso eu quero que essa fórmula seja dinâmica, onde através da função `=hoje()` o campo onde a fórmula `=PROCV(J7;JUL;6;JUL!C4:C35)` está, seja alimentado com o mês correto, mas ao fazer isso, buscando o valor de uma outra célula, é atribuído **String**, fazendo com que a fórmula encontre um erro, pois não é permitido **string** na fórmula (nessa parte no caso) pois seria o intervalo onde os dados que eu preciso, estão.

Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo do que preciso!]

Ao inserir a fórmula conforme a imagem, os dados recebidos ficam assim:

```
=PROCV(43651;$T$7;6;"JUL!C4:C35")
```

No campo **T7** tenho uma condição onde eu faço a verificação, se o mês atual for 1, então a saída é **"JAN"**, se for 2, então a saída é **"FEV"** e assim sucessivamente até **"DEZ"**.

No campo **T8** eu concateno o resultado da célula **T7** com o intervalo que eu preciso que é **!C4:35**.

O resultado traz dois erros...

---

1º - Onde deveria ser a ***matriz da tabela*** está recebendo **$T$7**.
Deveria receber a tabela em questão, no caso **JUL** (que é o mês atual)

2º - Onde deveria receber o intervalo dos dados está vindo como **string**.
Deveria receber sem as **aspas**, pra fórmula não encontrar o erro.

Tendo como resultado final da fórmula assim:

```
=PROCV(43651;JUL;6;JUL!C4:C35)
```

E está saindo assim:

```
=PROCV(43651;$T$7;6;"JUL!C4:C35")
```

---

**Como resolver isso ?**

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, poderia editar com um exemplo do que você realmente deseja e alguns dados fictícios?

Comment: Acho que ficou mais claro agora!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcos, boa tarde!

Acho que a fórmula está com as variáveis invertidas no seu exemplo.
Entendo que a forma correta seria:

```
=PROCV($T$7;INDIRETO(T8);6;0)
```

Faça um teste, talvez seja necessário usar o `INDIRETO` no `$T$7` também.

Abs!

Comment: Perfeito Paulo é isso mesmo, funcionou exatamente como eu queria!!
E a fórmula está correta, pois o primeiro parâmetro é onde eu pesquiso a data do dia, por isso é necessário colocar o campo J7. A fórmula ficou assim: =PROCV(J7;INDIRETO(T7);6;INDIRETO(T8)), trouxe exatamente como eu queria, obrigado!!